# How do I output only the current year when looping through records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How to show `<h2>2016</h2>` if `@past_challenges` `:deadline` doesn't include current year?

### view

```
<% if @past_challenges_without_deadline_for_current_year %>
  <h2>2016</h2>
<% end %>
```

### controller

```
@past_challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline < Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
@past_challenges_by_years = @past_challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year }
@past_challenges_without_deadline_for_current_year = ???
```

### db

```
t.date :deadline
```

[image]

### Tadman Attempt

```
<% if @past_challenges_by_years[Date.today.year] ||= [ ] %>
  <h2>2016</h2>
<% end %>
```

2016 is duplicated. The hope is that it only appears once.

[image]

Comment: You need to work on explaining your problems without getting all tangled up in your domain. You have to realize that other people have no clue what you are building. "How do I output only the current year when looping through records?" Not - "how do I make the foozle woozle the guzzle?"

Comment: Yea you're right @max. I've been trying to figure out how to approach this problem for hours and I just couldn't get my finger on what the heck I actually need to do or look for. This was the best my mind could mentally grapple with even though i think it is a simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're iterating over a list of things and want to introduce headers for each year, the most efficient method is to group them together by year using `group_by` like you've done there, then iterate over that data-set.

```
<% @past_challenges_by_years.each do |year, challenges| %>
  <h2><%= year%></h2>

  // ...
<% end %>
```

You can always special case each year if necessary by rendering them differently. Break those out with a `case` statement.

Comment: Thanks Tadman. Sorry I have that, but my problem is that I want to show the current year `2016` even if there are no `@past_challenges` with a `:deadline` in the current year. Now you could think why not just type it in and the problem with that is if there are `@past_challenges` with a `:deadline` for the current year than I don't want to duplicate the current year in two places. I want my typed in example to trigger if there are no `@past_challenges` with a `:deadline` set for the current year.

Comment: Then just jam in a dummy entry: `@past_challenges_by_years[Date.today.year] ||= [ ]`

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I updated the question with your attempt. Is there a way to only trigger the dummy entry if there are no `@past_challenges` with a `:deadline in the current year so that 2016 doesnt duplicate?

Comment: That code should do it. Give it a try and experiment.